# Use cout to print a number in a certain format (left align & right align)

Tags: c++

If I write code like this:

```cpp
int a = 123456;
cout << setw(20) << setiosflags(ios::right) << a << endl;
cout << setiosflags(ios::left) << setw(20) << a << '*' << endl;
```

On the 3rd line, I set the alignment as left align, so my expected output is

```
              123456
123456              *
```

but the REAL output is

```
              123456
              123456*
```

Why did that happen?

The IDE I use is DevCpp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::setiosflags()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setiosflags) sets new flags without clearing any existing flags. So on the 3rd line, you are enabling the `ios::left` flag without disabling the `ios::right` flag. It does not make sense to have both flags enabled at the same time, and it seems the stream prefers the `ios::right` flag if it is enabled.

Use [`std::left`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left) and [`std::right`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/right) instead. They reset the `ios::internal`, `ios::left`, and `ios::right` flags before setting the new alignment.

```cpp
int a = 123456;
cout << setw(20) << right << a << endl;
cout << left << setw(20) << a << '*' << endl;
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/kuEBDH)

Comment: Since it doesn't make sense,I think the compilor should use`ios::left`to cover `ios right`

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the line with `setiosflags(ios::right)`, it works as expected, so it seems all common compilers evaluate `right` before `left` and short circuit the program flow. Try either manually unsetting `ios::right`, or better yet, just use `std::left` like so:

```
cout << left << setw(20) << a << '\n';
```

This, as so many standard library functions, takes care of pesky details.

Answer (score 0):

```
int a = 123456;
cout.setf(ios::right, ios::adjustfield);
cout << setw(20) << a << endl;
cout.setf(ios::left, ios::adjustfield);
cout << setw(20) << a << '*' << endl;
```

If I recall, you need to reset the alignment.

Answer (score 0):

The `setiosflags` sets format flag for the output stream (here it's cout), not for this sentence only. Since the `ios::right` has priority over `ios::left`, the second line will be aligned right. So you need to clear the previous format flag and then set the new one.

```cpp
int a = 123456;
cout << setw(20) << setiosflags(ios::right) << a << endl;
cout << resetiosflags(ios::right) << setiosflags(ios::left) << setw(20) << a << '*' << endl;
```

But the simplest way is to use `std::left` and `std::right`

```cpp
int a = 123456;
cout << setw(20) << right << a << endl;
cout << left << setw(20) << a << '*' << endl;
```

Comment: So setiosflags sets the format flag for the program ,does `setiosflags(ios::setw(20))`sets the width for the whole program?